# How to make a call internal collections thread-safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, dictionary, collections, thread-safety

I have such class composition. Class declares a dictionary of objects that themselves have an internal dictionary objects.

```
    public class ValueObject
    {
        public float value = 0;
    }

    public class ValueDictionaryObject
    {
        private Dictionary<int, ValueObject> innerDict;

        public float GetTotalValue()
        {
            lock (((ICollection)this.innerDict).SyncRoot)
            {
                float total = 0f;
                foreach (var p in innerDict)
                    total += p.Value.value;
                return total;
            }
        }
    }

    public class OuterDictionaryObject
    {
        private Dictionary<int, ValueDictionaryObject> outerDict;

        public float GetTotalValueForSomeKey(int key )
        {
            lock (((ICollection)this.outerDict).SyncRoot)
            {
                return outerDict[key].GetTotalValue();
            }
        }
    }


    var outer = new OuterDictionaryObject();
```

I have problems when call from multiple threads, it seems happens deadlock

```
float result = outer.GetTotalValueForSomeKey(key);
```

How make this call thread safe?

Comment: You sometimes lock on the inner dictionary, sometimes on the outer dictionary. `GetTotalValue` and `GetTotalValueForSomeKey` are both public so depending in what order you try to call them, the locks may be taken in a different order and you get a deadlock.

What are you trying to do? This seems like a pretty complex setup.

Comment: I need a thread-safe way to get sum of values from inner dictionary

Comment: Are these dictionaries being modified while you need the sum? If yes, you should use `ConcurrentDictionary` instead.

Comment: I am working with .net 3.5 and am unable to use .net 4 (

Comment: Maybe use ReaderWriterLockSlim ?

Comment: Yes, that would probably alleviate some of the problems you may have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear from the code you posted why you'd get a deadlock. Yes, you have nested lock acquisition, which is a prerequisite for deadlock. But there's nothing here to show us how you've inverted the lock acquisition order in some scenario relative to the one we see here.

Still...

You should try to avoid calling anything as much as possible while holding a lock. Sometimes it's unavoidable (e.g. accessing a member of a collection you're synchronizing access to, which means you have to call a member of that collection). But you should only make calls when that's essential to the problem you're solving.

Here, it seems like you could have just as easily written the code like this:

```
public class OuterDictionaryObject
{
    private Dictionary<int, ValueDictionaryObject> outerDict;

    public float GetTotalValueForSomeKey(int key )
    {
        ValueDictionaryObject vdo;

        lock (((ICollection)this.outerDict).SyncRoot)
        {
            vdo = outerDict[key];
        }

        return vdo.GetTotalValue();
    }
}
```

Using `ConcurrentDictionary` would have a similar effect, in that you would not be calling the `GetTotalValue()` method until the synchronized access to the dictionary object had completed. So IMHO that would be a good option too.